# C# WPF Mouseover Button - no content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

I just edited this button.
Since I want to have a mouseover effect.
Unfortunately the content of Button is not displayed.
And I would like to change the font color, if I go with the mouse over it.

```
<Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="185" Height="50" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}" Canvas.Top="42">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF37424A"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF303B43"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unfortunately the content of Button is not displayed.

Don't set the Foreground property to `{x:Null}`:

> And I would like to change the font color, if I go with the mouse over it.

Add a setter that sets the `Foreground` property in your `IsMouseOver` trigger:

```
<Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="185" Height="50" 
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Canvas.Top="42">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF37424A"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF303B43"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```